# React hooks rules-of-hooks error in classes with Yup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, formik, yup

So before updating my app to react-scripts@4.0.0, I didn't have this error. I've followed this [guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/upgrade-create-react-app-based-projects-to-version-4-cra-4-d7962aee11a6) to make the upgrade. This is what I'm doing.

I've created a custom hook to implement Yup and set customized messages, use context, and other custom hooks:

```
    import * as Yup from 'yup';
    import { useAppContext } from '../context/AppContext';
    import { Locale } from '../utils/locale';
    import useLabel from './useLabel';

    const useYup = () => {
      const { state } = useAppContext();
      const { locale } = state;
      const { getLabel } = useLabel();

      const { requiredMessage } = {
        [Locale.PT_BR]: {
          requiredMessage: 'Este campo é obrigatório',
          // other messages
        },
        [Locale.EN_US]: {
          requiredMessage: 'This field is required',
          //other messages
        },
      }[locale];

      const name = Yup.string().min(2, minMessage(2)).max(150, maxMessage(150)).required(requiredMessage);
      // other fields 

      return { name };
    };

    export default useYup;
```

I'm using this in a lot of model classes for field validation, like this:

```
    import * as Yup from 'yup';
    import useYup from '../hooks/useYup';
    import { BusinessExpense } from './BusinessExpense.entity';

    export class Business {

      // other attributes
      businessName?: string = '';


      public static get validationSchema() {
        const { name: businessName } = useYup();

        return Yup.object({
          businessName
        });
      }
    }
```

From this, I'm using the validation schema with formik as recommended by the library, for example:

```
     const { values, handleChange, errors, touched, handleSubmit } = useFormik({
        initialValues: new Business(),
        validationSchema: Business.validationSchema,
        onSubmit,
      });
```

Finally, after the upgrade, it started to throw the error below. Any suggestions on how to fix it?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
src\model\Business.entity.ts
  Line 16:28:  React Hook "useYup" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a simple fix actually. I've modified the model class and removed the validation schema from a static method, and moved it to an outside function as another custom hook:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import useYup from '../hooks/useYup';
import { BusinessExpense } from './BusinessExpense.entity';

export class Business {

  businessName?: string = '';

}

export const useBusinessValidationSchema = () => {
  const { name: businessName} = useYup();

  return Yup.object({
    businessName,
  });
}
```

Then I can simply use like this in the formik setup:

```
import { Business, useBusinessValidationSchema } from '../../../model/Business.entity';

  const { values, handleChange, errors, touched, handleSubmit } = useFormik({
    initialValues: new Business(),
    validationSchema: useBusinessValidationSchema(),
    onSubmit,
  });
```

But if anyone has a better solution, I'd be glad to see it!